# Full Page width without using absolute Positioning

Tags: css, magento, css-position

I'm building this site (www.ellamatthew.com) in Magento. I need a full-width page but the way the Magento CSS is templated, I haven't been able to create it without using `"Position:absolute"` 100% width in CSS. This creates an issue with the footer not going below the image.

Here's the original Magento CSS that frames the page:

```
.col-left { float:left; width:182px; padding:0 0 0; margin:0 0 -1px; }
.col-main { float:left; width:715px; padding:0 20px 20px; }
.col-right { float:right; width:182px; padding:0 0 0; margin:0 0 -1px; }
```

Here's the custom CSS that I've put into Magento but it still doesn't recognize it. There's still a forced space on either side of .col-main:

```
.col-left { float:left; width:0px; padding:0 0 0; margin:0 0 -1px; }
.col-main {float:left; width:100%; height:100%; padding:0 10px 20px; }
.col-right { float:right; width:1px; padding:0 0 0; margin:0 0 -1px; }
.col1-layout .col-main { float:none; width:100%; padding-top:0px; }
```

Here's my absolute code:

```
.homepage {position: absolute;left:0px; top:150px; float:left; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

The footer is overlapped on the page when I do this. Does anyone have a solution to either force the body content to 100% or move the footer down below the absolute.

Any answers to any of these would be greatly appreciated as I've tried so many things with no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="main col1-layout">...</div>`

Try using `.main.col1-layout {float:none; width:100%; padding-top:0px;}`

### **EDIT**

To see how to do this, I looked at the source of the page (via inspect element in chrome, or firebug in firefox).  Then I looked at the various elements that could be causing the issue, and I noticed the css had it set to be 920px.  Once this was overridden it showed up correctly.  You might still have some issues with layouts more than 1 column wide (if you decide to use them).

Comment: Jason!! Oh My Goodness!! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!! You don't know how long I've been trying to get this to work. This worked just perfectly. I don't actually understand this piece of code and why it works differently but I'm just glad it works. Check out the link again to see it in action. http://www.ellamatthew.com/ Thanks again!! PS: Try to vote you up but apparently, I'm too new here.

Comment: Aaahh, sorry, just saw this!! Answer accepted :) Thanks again!!

Comment: Jason. Finally got got up privileges so thought I'd come back to pay my respect :)