# Change Magento Layout Width

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.9

I did some research, but i couldn't find any solution.
I am using Magento 1.9 CE and i want to change the Homepage width to full-width so i can create a full width slider. I did try to set a width to my page but it won't work.

This is the changes i made:

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
table,
 textarea {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width:1200px; <<<<<<---
          }
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the width of page then go to

```
/skin/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/css/styles.css
```

and Find "width:1200px" then change it to "width:1000px".

Read [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41344/change-the-size-of-homepage) but be careful as user said that by this image will be collapse so use it according to your need. Thanx

Another solution

```
<div class="main col1-layout">...</div>
```

Try using `.main.col1-layout {float:none; width:100%; padding-top:0px;}`

Source for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236344/full-page-width-without-using-absolute-positioning)